# trying to understand that a specific website utilizes X-FRAME-OPTIONS Http header or not

Tags: php, http-headers

how can I read the `Http headers` of a specific website with `Php`?
I need to know that a website utilizes `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `get_headers('url')` function to  Fetch all the headers sent by the server in response to an HTTP request